# Terminate/remove remote ssh shell from Mac terminal

Tags: linux, unix

I connected before with my school shell from my Mac at home. Now I would like to list the file from my local machine. After typed ls, it showed the contents inside my local machine. However after I typed e.g. cd applications-->applications username$ ls--> it showed my school file directory. How can I terminate school shell or just remove it forever? Tks!

After I typed exit, I got this
exit ssh remote server name
logout
-bash: exit: ssh: numeric argument required

[Process completed]

Answer (score 0):

Type exit [ENTER] or CTRL-D. It will quit remote shell

Comment: I DID. BUT AFTER I COME BACK, IT'S THE SAME ISSUE